# Unexpected Blast in Call of Duty 4

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I'm playing **Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare**, level
[No Fighting In The War Room](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/No_Fighting_In_The_War_Room). I read a lot of walkthroughs, but couldn't solve the problem.

First of all, you start as Soap MacTavish, with your teammates: Captain Price, SSgt Griggs, and Cpl Miller. The latter is is not mentioned in any walkthorugh I saw. He is a real coward, and engages in almost no fight. Despite this, he gets killed no matter how I try to save his life.

Anyway, I continued the level till I reached a corridor where crates blocked the road. There were two entries to my left and right, each leading to parallel side corridors. I entered each of them and killed every enemy. Oddly enough, neither Captain Price nor SSgt Griggs followed me.

After that, killing all enemies in side corridors, I took a path leading to the main corridor (bypassing the wooden crates which blocked the road). At the moment I set foot on the passage joining the side corridor to the main one, an alarm set off.

I sprinted to the main corridor, meeting Price & Griggs! They were running towards some giant door. No matter how fast I ran, just before entering the door, something exploded, and I was dead!

This explosion is not mentioned in any walkthrough. I think it might be related to Cpl Miller's death, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question on my part but are you watching the level timer? If you're on a high difficulty (namely veteran) and taking your time in the level an alarm will set off and all missles will launch, killing you.

Comment: @thethinman: Thanks for the comment. The answer is yes, I had an eye for the timer. I had at least 7 mins left (in recruit difficulty) so the timer is not the problem. I even tested this in front of someone who have had finished the game, and he said he has never seen this before.

Comment: Alright well that is strange. +1 and hopefully someone else can help. I unfortunately don't have cod 4 anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thing you should always keep in mind with Call of Duty games is that the action sequences are completely scripted.  Basically, what that means is the game will keep throwing enemies at you or will otherwise not progress the level until you initiate a specific action.  In this case, you are faced with this corridor:

[image: Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare - Corridor filling with flammable gas]

The corridor is filling up with flammable gas.  Once you pass a specific point in this corridor, shortly after exiting one of the side corridors, Captain Price will say *Go! Go! Go!*  This is your queue that the corridor will be detonated by the opposition.  If you listen carefully, you can hear a countdown on the overhead speaker in Russian.  You need to make a mad dash to the end of this corridor and exit it before Captain Price shuts the door.  He will shout out *Move! Move!* right before he shuts the door.

I would suggest sprinting for this door as soon as you exit one of the side corridors and make it through the door before Captain Price shuts it, thus:

[image: Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare - Exiting corridor before Captain Price shuts the door]

Comment: Thanks. As you said, the corridor is filled with flammable gas. I sprinted as fast as I could, and reached within inches of the door, but it blasted and I died. I repeated this for, maybe, 10 times, and the result was the same. And...Captain Price never said "Go! Go! Go!" during this. I suspect this behavior is because I failed to save "Cpl Miller". Have you reached the door while Cpl Miller was alive?

Comment: @Del I've just played through the mission again and I don't see a Cpl. Miller anywhere in the level.  I run through the mission with Captain Price, Sgt. Griggs and Sgt. Grant.  Sgt. Grant does not make it through the blast door, and honestly I lost track of him well before that.  Would it help you if I took a video of me playing through that portion of the level so you can see what I do?

Comment: The name "Cpl. Miller" seems to be chosen at random! After running several times, I got names like [Pvt. Dowd](http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/2531626shot0002.jpg), [Cpl. Clarke](http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/4692656shot0003.jpg), [Cpl. Dowd](http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/5133716shot0004.jpg), and [Sgt. Boyd](http://s1.bild.me/bilder/311010/1579234shot0005.jpg). If you lost track of him, then he must have nothing to do with the blast. Thanks for the video suggestion, but that's a pain for you, and I'm not gonna bother you. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure its gas? I think its just steam and the fire comes, because they are launching a missile..

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas Come to think of it, you are probably right.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old  question, but as I can see, it has not been solved.

What you are describing is a simple case of bugged game. As mentioned in above answer, this game has no sandbox effect what so ever -- everything is scripted. And there are triggers, like everybody waits for you, while you wonder inside previously cleared room AND when you go near them -> past a trigger-point, then new objectives appear and everybody starts running..

In your case, this trigger is bugged.. You have to reinstall you game in this case. I normally know all the COD4 related glitches and cases, but this is something new..

Comment: It shouldn't be bugged enough that it occurs over and over again.

Comment: @Simon: Well I meant that the game is absolutely broken. Technically you need skills to stay behind on a trigger point. This issue shouldn't happen, but if it happens every time, then the game is of course bugged/broken.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going through both the corridors? You only need to go through one. Once you see Price and the others run through the hall, follow them. Don't keep going straight to the next one.